# Nginx returning blank HTML pages with php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

I'm using php-fpm through Nginx.

My nginx.conf can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Nu9iD8Km
It includes a file found here: http://pastebin.com/ece4cwXF
My php-fpm.conf can be found here (all the options omitted are the default): http://pastebin.com/70fBE30E
My fastcgi_params file is similar to the default, but adds this line, following a recommendation on the web:
`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`

I keep getting blank pages instead of PHP scripts, but static stuff loads fine. What's weird is that I'm not getting 404 errors - my browser tells me that the status code is 200 OK.

Neither nginx or php-fpm's logs turn up anything interesting. What may be causing this?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Update: now some scripts are working, but phpBB is still returning blank pages. How can I diagnose/fix this issue?

Comment: Finally got lazy and used the php-fpm PPA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My php section looks like this:

```
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fastcgi.socket;
    }
```

My listen directive in php-fpm.conf this:

```
listen = /dev/shm/php-fastcgi.socket
```

Could you also provide your php-fpm.conf? 
If the error still exists, please enable logging in fpm and provide fpm logs:

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

Comment: Added php-fpm.conf to original question. The PHP log file (fpm-php.www.log) isn't even being created, so I guess it's not logging anything, since it doesn't return any file-related errors in the main FPM log.

Comment: Now it's been created, due to a script error.

Comment: ok, and still no errors inside the logfiles?
Could you enable also "php_flag[display_errors] = on" in your php-fpm.conf? Afterwards, still white page and no error on your page neither in fpm-php.log or nginx error log?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue - blank pages without warning - `short_open_tag = On` solved the problem.
Check php.ini `short_open_tag` is it ON or OFF? If you use shortcuts like `<?=$test?>` or if you open tags with just `<?` it should be set to ON.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it - I'm trying to get phpBB to work, and it uses long/regular <?php ?> tags

Comment: Do you have display_errors = On in your php.ini?

Comment: Is there a way for PHP fpm to report errors like these instead of forcing the developer to run in circles to figure out what happened? Thanks!